# Java object initialisation in constructor

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java and stuck on the following Java class:

```
public class Score {

private Paint paint;
private int score;

// Constructor
public Score(Context color) {
    paint = new Paint();
    // Set the font face and size of drawing text
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    paint.setTextSize(24);
    paint.setColor(color);

    // TODO initialize score

}

public void incrementScore() {
    // TODO Increment score
}

public void decrementScore() {
    // TODO Decrement score
}

public int getScore() { return score; }

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    // TODO use drawText(String, x co-ordinate, y-coordinate, paint) to
    // draw text on the canvas. Position the text at (10,30).
}
}
```

I want to initialize the score in the Constructor as mentionned in the TO DO, but anytime I create a new object with

```
 score = new Score();
```

I run into typecasting issues that I don´t get solved. Anytime, I want to instantiate an object as above, I get the package name as a return value from this object, but I need an integer value. Why is that? I know, this covers basic Java questions, but as I said, I´m new to Java. Any hints and code snippets would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: In a singleton class you create a new instance of the object in his own constructor, but its not the case here

Comment: @Pablo Singleton doesn't do it either.

Comment: Ok, I found this very strange aswell; but this is an example of a Java class from a Computer science online course and I need to do the TO DO´s as an exercise. This also seems very strange to me, but I thought, may be I´m missing out on something. So why should the object be instantiated in the constructor itself? What would be a good solution to this problem and the TO DO?

Comment: @DWA2112: Just think about what `score` is, what value you might assign to it. It certainly isn't `new Score()`, that doesn't make any sense on multiple levels. Just logically, what *number* (it's an `int`, after all) would make a good initial `score`?

Comment: If I initialise it like this as an integer variable:  score=0; the package name is always stored in this variable and I don´t know why. Why should the package name be stored in this variable as it is? When I use the variable in this class, it always gives me the package name as a value, not null or something. That´s what I don´t understand.

Comment: @AndyThomas Yeah, I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: i mean one of his own methods (static)

Comment: @DWA2112 - When you say "the package name is always stored in this variable," what variable are you referring to, and what are you seeing that suggests the package name is stored in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a typecasting error because you have a variable in your class called `score` which is of type `int`. So when you say something like

```
score = new Score();
```

You're trying to set an integer as an object of type `Score`. If you want to initialize score, you'll have to do something like

```
score = 20;
```